# Can't Call GCP Python Google Cloud Function with Body Parameters in x-www-form-urlencoded Via Postman

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, postman, gcloud

I have a python3.9 GCP cloud function deployed. It's the default function for python3.9. I set this function up as an HTTP triggered, Allow unauthenticated invocations function. The `gcloud deploy` command for this function is this:

```bash
gcloud functions deploy test_one \
--memory=256MB \
--runtime=python39 \
--trigger-http \
--project=<PROJECT_ID> \
--security-level=secure-always \
--entry-point=hello_world \
--max-instances=10 \
--service-account=<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL> \
--source=deploy_test_one/
```

I have the following `main.py` file in the `deploy_test_one/` directory:

```
def hello_world(request):
    """Responds to any HTTP request.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): HTTP request object.
    Returns:
        The response text or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using
        `make_response <http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.make_response>`.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json()
    if request.args and 'message' in request.args:
        return request.args.get('message')
    elif request_json and 'message' in request_json:
        return request_json['message']
    else:
        return f'Hello World!'
```

And I noticed that when I use postman to call this function, it doesn't accept my input for `x-www-form-urlencoded`:
[image]

But it does accept my input when I give this data in the `raw` setting as json?
[image]

How can I modify this default python function or my settings to accept `x-www-form-urlencoded` parameters?

Comment: The HTTP header Content-Type will tell you how the data is formatted (if the header was set correctly by the client). Process the header and call the correct code. There are multiple formats for uploading (POST) data. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST It is up to you to write code that supports the formats that clients use else return an error to the client.

Comment: But how would you change the actual default python function to accept x-www-form-urlencoded data? `request.get_json()` and `request.args` don't work so what would I change them too?

Comment: See the example in Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#parsing_http_requests). Check the `Content-Type` for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and then `request.form.get`.

Comment: I recommend reading the specs on how HTTP POST works and the various data formats. The example that @DazWilikin provided is a start, but there are many details you must understand.